# apache .htaccess rewrite should not include www

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We have a domain test.com, we want to redirect http://www.test.com to http://test.com and https://www.test.com to https://test.com, We can achieve the same by below mentioned rule, but we dont want http:// and beside what do we have to do for https://

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single rule to handle both `http` and `https` traffic:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything to go to https, then you need to change your rule to:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Otherwise, you'll need separate rules for http and https:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```